# Table with combobox on one of fild data-binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I need create table with field with combobox on page. But I can't bind valid items to combobox, all combobox have default values - 'Please Select...'. Can you help me?

My html code fragment:

```
        <td><label data-bind="text: name"></label></td>
        <td><label data-bind="text: description"></label></td>`enter code here`
        <td>
            <select class="controls contol-width span2" id="cmbSelectedInfo" required="required" data-bind="
            options: vm.infoes,
            value: vm.selectedInfoID,
            optionsText:'code',
            optionsValue: 'infoID',
            optionsCaption: 'Please Select...'"></select>
        </td>
```

My viewmodel in typescript:

```
 class MyViewModel {
        infoes: KnockoutObservableArray<any>;
        selectedInfoID: KnockoutObservable<number>;

        constructor() {
            this.infoes = ko.observableArray(); 
            this.selectedInfoID = ko.observable<number>();
        }

        getInfoes(url: string, onError: (message: string) => {}) {
            (<any>this).getJson(url, (data: any) => {
                <any>this.infoes((<any>ko).mapping.fromJS(data).infoes());          
            } ,(message: string) => { 
                onError(message);
            });
        }

        getJson(url: string, onSuccessed: (data: any) => {}, onError: (message: string) => {}) {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',           
                success: (data) => {                
                    if (data.succeeded) {
                        onSuccessed(data);
                    } else {
                        onError((<any>data).error);
                    }
                },          
                error: (data) => {
                    onError((<any>data).error);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting different values from the Json call?

Comment: Where is the code that creates the viewmodel object and calls getInfoes?

Comment: @Wayne Ellery, yes you are right

Comment: @G_S, yes yes I'm sure. I get different values in json

Comment: I solved the problem with change value: $data.infoID